# How to convert a function in a third party library to be async?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am using my Raspberry Pi and the `pigpio` and `websockets` libraries.

I want my program to run asynchronously (i.e. I will use `async def main` as the entry point).

The `pigpio` library expects a synchronous [callback function](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#callback) to be called in response to events, which is fine, but from within that callback I want to call another, *asynchronous* function from the `websocket` library.

So it would look like:

```
def sync_cb(): # <- This can not be made async, therefore I can not use await
   [ws.send('test') for ws in connected_ws] # <- This is async and has to be awaited
```

Currently I can get it to work with:

```
def sync_cb():
    asyncio.run(asyncio.wait([ws.send('test') for ws in connected_ws]))
```

but the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) say this use of `asyncio.run` is discouraged.

So my synchronous callback needs to call `ws.send` (also from a [third party library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)) which is async from a function that is synchronous.

Another option that works is:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[ws.send(json.dumps(message)) for ws in connected_ws]))
```

But the three lines of creating and setting an even loop sounds like a lot just to run a simple async function.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to substitute an async function where a synchronous callback is required (i.e. is there a way to make `cb` async in this example)
- And, what kind of overhead am I incurring by using `asyncio.run` and `asyncio.wait` just to call a simple async method (in the list comprehension)

Comment: If the library is written in asyncio and expects a _non-async_ callback, you have a problem. I am surprised thatsing `asyncio.run()` doesn't raise an exception when run inside another event loop. Also, if you need to call essentially blocking code inside your callback, you could block the outer event loop indefinitely.

Comment: It is also unclear what is `connected_ws` - if those are live websocket connections created under some event loops, I don't think you can just hand them to a *different* event loop (`asyncio.run` creates a new event loop every time, much like the three lines in the second part of your question). Even if it happens to work right now, it might stop working without notice - it's not a supported way to use asyncio.

Comment: There are two libraries. One requires a non-async callback, and one requires async callbacks.  I want to call one of the async library functions from within the non-async function.

Comment: The confusing part is that you start the question with "I am trying to write a program using this library that runs entirely in an asyncio event loop", and then the next sentence says that "the library expects a [sync] callback function". Do the two paragraphs actually refer to two different libraries?

Comment: I updated the question. It's simply "how do I `await` an async function from within a synchronous function

Comment: In your place I'd create a dedicated thread with an event loop that just runs `loop.run_forever()`, and submit coroutines to that loop using `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`. That function returns a `concurrent.futures.Future` (not to be confused with `asyncio.Future`) with a sync `result()` method which will not only wait for the coroutine to finish, but also propagate the return value (or the exception, if one was raised). That way you avoid problems with `asyncio.run()` creating a new event loop each time. As for the overhead, it won't be free - measure it to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) function returning `concurrent.furures.Future`, which can be waited synchronously, to wrap coroutine to regular function and call it from synchronous code.

As I understand it, this approach is more appropriate if sync code (of third party lib) is executed in separate thread, but it can be adapted to single-threaded execution with some modifications.

An example to illustrate the approach:

```py
import asyncio


def async_to_sync(loop, foo):
    def foo_(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(foo(*args, **kwargs), loop).result()  
    return foo_


def sync_code(cb):
    for i in range(10):
        cb(i)


async def async_cb(a):
    print("async callback:", a)


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_code, async_to_sync(loop, async_cb))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
async callback: 0
async callback: 1
async callback: 2
...
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `return` in `foo_`.

Comment: Yes, it would be better

Comment: @AlexNoname I appreciate your example, but it seems easier to just run the function without `run_in_executor`.  I updated my example.  Ideally I would be able to skip all this creation of event loops.

Comment: it is always better to provide an minimal reproducible example, because now it is not clear to me how you want to “run entirely in an asyncio event loop”, but at the same time “skip all this creation of event loops”

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to substitute an async function where a synchronous callback is required

It is possible. You can run event loop in separate thread and emit `async` code there, but you have to consider GIL.

```py
import asyncio
import threading

class Portal:

    def __init__(self, stop_event):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.stop_event = stop_event

    async def _call(self, fn, args, kwargs):
        return await fn(*args, **kwargs)

    async def _stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()

    def call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self._call(fn, args, kwargs), self.loop)

    def stop(self):
        return self.call(self._stop)

def create_portal():
    portal = None

    async def wait_stop():
        nonlocal portal
        stop_event = asyncio.Event()
        portal = Portal(stop_event)
        running_event.set()
        await stop_event.wait()

    def run():
        asyncio.run(wait_stop())

    running_event = threading.Event()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    thread.start()
    running_event.wait()

    return portal
```

Usage example:

```py
async def test(msg):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print(msg)
    return "HELLO " + msg

# it'll run a new event loop in separate thread
portal = create_portal()
# it'll call `test` in the separate thread and return a Future 
print(portal.call(test, "WORLD").result())
portal.stop().result()
```

In your case:

```
def sync_cb():
    calls = [portal.call(ws.send, 'test') for ws in connected_ws]
    # if you want to get results from these calls:
    # [c.result() for c in calls]
```

> And, what kind of overhead am I incurring by using asyncio.run and asyncio.wait just to call a simple async method

`asyncio.run` will create a new event loop and close it then. Most likely if the callback is not called often it won't be a problem. But if you will use `asyncio.run` in another callback too, then they won't be able to work concurrently.